# RangeTool update on event in bokeh

Tags: slider, bokeh

I'm trying to compute some statistics on a given range of data from a plot  using a bokeh app. For selecting the range I am using RangeTool. However I cannot find the way to detect the event. I'm using as base this example:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/range_tool.html

Then I tried:

```
def func():
    print(range_rool._property_values['x_range'].start)
    return 
def func_e(event):
    print('event detected')
    return

range_rool.on_event(ButtonClick,func_e)
range_rool.on_event(Press,func)    
range_rool.on_change("x_range",func)
```

but when I move the slider I don't see any difference. Any idea very welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RangeTool` updates the range it is configured with, you can (and should) just add callbacks on the range itself, e.g.:

```
range_tool.x_range.on_change('start', ...)
```

Regarding the line `range_rool.on_change("x_range",func)` that you have, it's worth explaining that that instructs Bokeh to run `func` when the range object itself is wholesale replaced, i.e.

```
range_tool.x_range = some_new_Range1d
```

would trigger that callback. But the range is never normally replaced liked that. Instead, the `start` and `end` values of a single range are updated over time.

Also, as an aside, there is never any valid reason at all to access `_properties`. It is a private API and subject to change at any time.